# Packer fails on Gitlab-CI with {message:401 Unauthorized}: command not found

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, packer

I am trying to use packer with GCP in gitlab-ci but every time I get to the packer build it will fail with the following error:

```
starting remote command: chmod +x /tmp/script_5147.sh; DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='googlecompute' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='my_vm'  /tmp/script_5147.sh
==> googlecompute.my_vm: /tmp/script_5147.sh: line 1: {message:401 Unauthorized}: command not found
2022/11/13 13:26:05 [INFO] 0 bytes written for 'stdout'
2022/11/13 13:26:05 packer-plugin-googlecompute_v1.0.16_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2022/11/13 13:26:05 [ERROR] Remote command exited with '127': chmod +x /tmp/script_5147.sh; DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='googlecompute' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='my_vm'  /tmp/script_5147.sh
2022/11/13 13:26:05 packer-plugin-googlecompute_v1.0.16_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2022/11/13 13:26:05 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 127
```

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

apt update
apt install -y curl
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
apt upgrade -y iptables
# The iptables-persistent must be installed in order to create the /etc/iptables/rules.v4 file
apt install -y nginx libzmq3-dev nodejs ipset iptables-persistent net-tools libre2-dev
npm install -g yarn

rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

The packer is working locally (also with the image) and I created a VM in GCP all of them are working, only in gitlab it fails.

I created a custom image of packer and it still failed for me on gitlab.

I will try to move it to my own runner but it will take a few days for me.

Would love if someone could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem.
I curled some files and the token was not good so when it got to packer it failed because the files were not as expected.
I printing the 401 of the curl.